# MySQL - Use derived column names in the subsequent comparisons

Tags: mysql

I have following two tables:

(I apologise for being unable to paste them properly here, so have created a snapshot and given the link to it):

**Table Exams**

```
+---------+------------+-------------+  
| exam_id | exam_date  | description |  
+---------+------------+-------------+  
|       1 | 2016-06-01 | Exam 1      |  
|       2 | 2016-06-06 | Exam 2      |  
|       3 | 2016-06-07 | Exam 3      |  
|       4 | 2016-06-10 | Exam 4      |  
+---------+------------+-------------+
```

**Table Subjects**

```
+------------+---------+-------------+  
| subject_id | exam_id | result      |  
+------------+---------+-------------+  
|          1 |       1 | Attended    |  
|          2 |       1 | Fail        |  
|          3 |       2 | Distinction |  
|          4 |       2 | Distinction |  
|          5 |       3 | Pass        |  
|          6 |       3 | Distinction |  
|          7 |       4 | Attended    |  
|          8 |       4 | Pass        |  
+------------+---------+-------------+
```

The possible values in the "result" field are:

*Fail, Attended, Pass, Distinction*

The aim is to get the overall result for an exam depending on the grades achieved in the subordinate subjects for that exam - "fail" in one subject within that exam would mean that the overall result is "fail". "Attended" means that the result in that subject is indeterministic as yet and unless any other subjects have already resulted in a "fail" grade, the result could only be called "attended". Likewise, "distinction" can only be attained when it's been achieved in all the subjects within that exam.

Query:

```
SELECT exams.exam_id, exam_date, description, 
@count_fail         :=  SUM(result='Fail')          AS count_fail, 
@count_attended     :=  SUM(result='Attended')      AS count_attended, 
@count_pass         :=  SUM(result='Pass')          AS count_pass, 
@count_distinction  :=  SUM(result='Distinction')   AS count_distinction,
CASE 
    WHEN (@count_fail >= @count_attended AND @count_fail >= 1)
        THEN 'Fail'
    WHEN (@count_attended >= @count_pass AND @count_attended >= 1)
        THEN 'Attended'
    WHEN (@count_pass >= @count_distinction AND @count_pass>= 1)    
        THEN 'Pass'
    ELSE 
        'Distinction'
    END AS final_result FROM exams 
INNER JOIN subjects ON exams.exam_id = subjects.exam_id GROUP BY exam_id
```

The results have stumped me...

```
+---------+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
| exam_id | exam_date  | description | count_fail | count_attended | count_pass | count_distinction | final_result |
+---------+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
|       1 | 2016-06-01 | Exam 1      |          1 |              1 |          0 |                 0 |  Distinction |
|       2 | 2016-06-06 | Exam 2      |          0 |              0 |          0 |                 2 |  Fail        |
|       3 | 2016-06-07 | Exam 3      |          0 |              0 |          1 |                 1 |  Distinction |
|       4 | 2016-06-10 | Exam 4      |          0 |              1 |          1 |                 0 |  Pass        |
+---------+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Please may I ask what's going on here? How are the WHEN conditions not met (it's evident that some sort of calculation is taking place in @ variables, since the output isn't all gibberish)? This is just a small scale illustration of the bigger scheme of things, that I unfortunately can't get into the finer details of. However, I really want to avoid using nested queries and stick with the JOINS as much as possible...

I'll really be very grateful to receive your inputs and suggestions.

Many Thanks!

**EDIT**

The SQL Fiddle for the DB and the query is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa15ef/2)

The output that was expected was:

```
+---------+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
| exam_id | exam_date  | description | count_fail | count_attended | count_pass | count_distinction | final_result |
+---------+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
|       1 | 2016-06-01 | Exam 1      |          1 |              1 |          0 |                 0 |  Fail        |
|       2 | 2016-06-06 | Exam 2      |          0 |              0 |          0 |                 2 |  Distinction |
|       3 | 2016-06-07 | Exam 3      |          0 |              0 |          1 |                 1 |  Pass        |
|       4 | 2016-06-10 | Exam 4      |          0 |              1 |          1 |                 0 |  Attended    |
+---------+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

**Reasons being:**

*Row 1:* The lowest grade possible (fail) is achieved in at least one of the subjects and hence the overall result must be "fail"

*Row 2:* Both the subjects in that exam have been cleared with a distinction grade and hence the overall result should be "distinction"

*Row 3:* 1 Pass, 1 Distinction. This result can't be a distinction, however, it isn't a "fail" either. Since both the subjects under this exam have been cleared (although one of them isn't with a distinction grade), the result should be "Pass".

*Row 4:* 1 Attended, 1 Pass. The counts aren't enough to conclude that the overall result will be "Pass" (since "attended" is indeterministic). Therefore, the overall result will only qualify as "attended" (until the point that all subjects within that exam are cleared with "Pass", or there's at least one "fail", consequently leading the overall result to be called "Fail". As it stands, "distinction" is now not achievable since at least one subject within this exam has already been registered with a lower pass grade)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of anything on SO.  Your links are broken and it's much easier to work with text then to have to rewrite everything in your test data.  The way you have it now is fine.

Comment: @Dresden, Apologies, I wasn't able to paste the tables correctly before. Thank you for helping with the edits, will follow the suggestion of not posting the pictures henceforth. Thanks.

Comment: can you create a sqlfiddle and a table above showing expected results

Comment: @Drew, Fiddle link and additional details are now added. Hopefully that's ok? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using user defined variables? Generally speaking, these variables are rarely used. In your specific example, variables should not be needed. All that being said, the [documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) state **the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.**

Comment: @DhruvSaxena thx. I will take a look in a while if no one latches onto it (which I hope they do)

Comment: @AgRizzo At first, I tried using the derived column names "count_" directly. Though this was good enough for computing the counts of subjects resulting in attended, fail, pass or distinction within that exam, it wasn't sufficient for deriving the "final_result". MySQL syntax didn't permit their reuse in comparisons that I intend to make in the WHEN clauses.. Hope I'm making sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [solution as shown in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa15ef/3) without user defined variables

```
SELECT exams.exam_id, exam_date, description, 
SUM(result='Fail')          AS count_fail, 
SUM(result='Attended')      AS count_attended, 
SUM(result='Pass')          AS count_pass, 
SUM(result='Distinction')   AS count_distinction,
CASE 
    WHEN (SUM(result='Fail') >= SUM(result='Attended') AND SUM(result='Fail') >= 1)
        THEN 'Fail'
    WHEN (SUM(result='Attended') >= SUM(result='Pass')  AND SUM(result='Attended') >= 1)
        THEN 'Attended'
    WHEN (SUM(result='Pass')  >= SUM(result='Distinction') AND SUM(result='Pass') >= 1)    
        THEN 'Pass'
    ELSE 
        'Distinction'
    END AS final_result FROM exams 
INNER JOIN subjects ON exams.exam_id = subjects.exam_id
GROUP BY exam_id
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
Please may I ask if there's anything to be wary about the SUM() operation if there were several qualifiable rows - will the SUM be recalculated for every expression?

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a row `(9, 1, 'Attended');` tacked onto the end. Plus the question itself is lacking in description of what `Pass` even means. As usual on the stack, lack of boundary test data and clear questions.

Comment: @Drew, Thanks for the observation! I'm sorry that the question appeared unclear. The "Pass" grade can only be achieved when all the subjects within an exam have been cleared with either a "Pass" or a "Distinction" grade (but not all "Distinction"), and without any "Attended" or "Fail" classification. So, with great thanks to your observation, it seems the query can be modified in the WHEN clauses to remove all the conditions preceding AND to get the desired result!

Comment: I apologize if that came off too harsh. I am sure you can take it from what AgRizzo gave :p